# HERE maps Get cardinal points using Bounds

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I need to get the location of the cardinal points using Here Api javascript, I am using the following code:

```js
var bounds = map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds;
                console.log(bounds.getBoundingBox());
```

And the result that I get is these values and I don't know what value is north, south, east and west.

```
K {ba: -79.39228887213605, ga: -79.38982123984238, ja: 43.6432819654959, la: 43.641401124059136, b: null, …}
a: null
b: null
ba: -79.39228887213605
c: null
ga: -79.38982123984238
ja: 43.6432819654959
la: 43.641401124059136
__proto__: Wf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question with the following lines of code:

```
var bounds = map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds;
var points = bounds.getBoundingBox();
var top = points.getTop();
var left = points.getLeft();
var right = points.getRight();
var bottom = points.getBottom();
```

Comment: it's documented here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/H.geo.Rect.html